# Driver package for Herculex motor

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any driver package for dongbu herculex motor available in ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202151/driver-package-for--herculex-motor/) by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-01-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be a little late for you but in case anyone else is looking for the same answer here is what I've found.

The [herkulex_servo_controler repo here](https://github.com/lukaszmitka/herkulex_servo_controller) contains a simple ROS node to control a single servo that could easily be expanded to control any number of servos. I'm about to start using these servo's for a project myself so I'll try using this package as a starting point and will extend it to drive any number of servo's

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0